# Segmentation fault: 11 when loading Haystack DensePassageRetriever

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, nlp-question-answering, haystack

I am trying to run this Question Answering model using this doc https://haystack.deepset.ai/tutorials/12_lfqa, but running into segmentation fault as below. I am using Python 3.9.17. May laptop has 64 GB RAM, and when I checked the Activity Monitory while running below, Memory used is around 16.8 GB. So, not sure what is causing this issue.

```
>>> retriever = DensePassageRetriever(
...     document_store=document_store,
...     query_embedding_model="vblagoje/dpr-question_encoder-single-lfqa-wiki",
...     passage_embedding_model="vblagoje/dpr-ctx_encoder-single-lfqa-wiki",
... )
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_utils.py:776: UserWarning: TypedStorage is deprecated. It will be removed in the future and UntypedStorage will be the only storage class. This should only matter to you if you are using storages directly.  To access UntypedStorage directly, use tensor.untyped_storage() instead of tensor.storage()
  return self.fget.__get__(instance, owner)()
Segmentation fault: 11
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
bash-3.2$
```

Can any one help me with this issue?

Comment: I see you're using Anaconda, that's not officially supported. Have you tried using `pip`?

Comment: Thanks @SilvanoCerza Problem got resolved after I switched to /usr/bin/python3